# Function which eliminates specific elements from a list in an efficient way

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I want to create a function (without using libraries) which takes as input three integer numbers (>0) (**a**,**b**,**c**) , for example:

```
a = 6
b = 6
c = 3
```

and returns a list containing **c** elements (so in this case the returned list should contain 3 elements) taken from a list of **a** numbers (so in this case the initial list is [1,2,3,4,5,6]). The **c** elements of the returned list have to be the ones that managed to remain in the initial list after removing a number every **b** positions from the list of **a** elements until len(return_list) = **c**.

So for **a** = 6, **b** = 6 and **c** = 3 the function should do something like this:

```
1) initial_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6] 
2) first_change = [2,3,4,5,6] #the number after the 6th (**b**) is 1 because after the last element you keep counting returning to the first one, so 1 is canceled
3) second_change = [2,4,5,6] #you don't start to count positions from the start but from the first number after the eliminated one, so new number after the 6th is 3 and so 3 is canceled
4) third_change = [2,4,5] #now the number of elements in the list is equal to **c**
```

Notice that if, when counting, you end up finishing the elements from the list, you keep the counting and return to the first element of the list.

I made this function:

```
def findNumbers(a,b,c):  
count = 0
dictionary = {}
countdown = a
for x in range(1,a+1):
    dictionary[x] = True
while countdown > c:
    for key,value in dictionary.items():
        if value == True:
            count += 1
            if count == b+1:
                dictionary[key] = False
                count = 0
                countdown -= 1
return [key for key in dictionary.keys() if dictionary[key] == True]
```

It works in some cases, like the above example. But it doesn't work everytime.
For example:

```
findNumbers(1000,1,5)
```

returns:

```
[209, 465, 721, 977]    #wrong result
```

instead of:

```
[209, 465, 721, 849, 977] #right result
```

and for bigger numbers, like:

```
findNumbers(100000, 200000, 5)
```

it takes too much time to even do its job, I don't know if the problem is the inefficiency of my algorithm or because there's something in the code that gives problems to Python. I would like to know a different approach to this situation which could be both more efficient and able to work in every situation. Can anyone give me some hints/ideas?
Thank you in advance for your time. And let me know if you need more explanations and/or examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track of the index of the last list item deleted like this:

```
def findNumbers(a, b, c):
    l = list(range(1, a + 1))
    i = 0
    for n in range(a - c):
        i = (i + b) % (a - n)
        l.pop(i)
    return l
```

so that `findNumbers(6, 6, 3)` returns:

```
[2, 4, 5]
```

and `findNumbers(1000, 1, 5)` returns:

```
[209, 465, 721, 849, 977]
```

and `findNumbers(100000, 200000, 5)` returns:

```
[10153, 38628, 65057, 66893, 89103]
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I could be recursive about the problem, so I wrote this:

```
def func(a,b,c):
  d = [i+1 for i in range(a)]
  def sub(d,b,c):
    if c == 0: return d
    else:
      k = b % len(d)
      d.pop(k)
      d = d[k:] + d[:k]
      return sub(d,b,c-1)
  return sub(d,b,a-c)
```

so that `func(6,6,3)` returns: `[2, 4, 5]` successfully and `func(1000,1,5)` returns: `[209, 465, 721, 849, 977]` unfortunately with an error.

It turns out that for values of `a > 995`, the below flag is raised:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

There was no need to try `func(100000,200000,5)` - lesson learnt.

Still, rather than dispose of the code, I decided to share it. It could serve as a recursive thinking precautionary.

Comment: @blhsing if you don't mind me asking _here_ (I cannot ask above), how did you come about your code? I couldn't quite wrap my head around it.